# Saving mysql database in file, to be distributed to teacher along with python application

Tags: python, mysql

I've made a python application the relies on a mysql database. Is there anyway I could somehow save the mysql database into a file format along with the code to be distributed to my teacher? He needs to be able to view the code and run it, so I am not able to export it to a .exe file. I'm currently using MYSQL workbench to run my database on mac. Where as my teacher uses a PC and uses Microsoft access

Basically, I want it where I have a folder that container my program saved as a .py file, and the mysql file in the same folder, and my teacher will simply open my code and run it, and the program fully works and runs with the database fully integrated.

Comment: No, your teacher must install mysql locally or there must be a server that both of you can access with mysql installed on it. You should clarify with your teacher how to submit your application.

Comment: in pricple you could give him a docker, with all inlcusive and he could start it and access it from there. The same goes for an virtual machine like virtualbox. but both need the software to run these

Comment: Yes, I do believe my teacher has mysql installed, but we use completely different software. I'm new to mysql, so I don't know much on the technical side of the mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 options.
Option A would be to export a so called MySQL dump, send it with the files and use Python to import it into the MySQL database. This option requires that your teacher **has MySQL installed**.

Option B would be to not use a database application and work with a CSV file instead. With this option you can just send the CSV file with your code. This option obviously requires to change your Python code so it uses the CSV file instead of the database.

**From my point of view (I may miss something) you should not have a database installer in your files which installs a DB on your teachers‘ computer**

Comment: Minor correction: You mean MySQL *dump*.  Additionally, Python is overkill for a dump file; as the dump file contains the schema and table create statements, *and* the data.  Just pipe the .sql file into a CLI mysql instance.

Comment: @S3DEV I see your point, but my thoughts behind the MySQL dump are that the teacher may have not the database scheme yet. With this I wanted to meet the requirement: _Basically, I want it where I have a folder that container my program saved as a .py file, and the mysql file in the same folder, and my teacher will simply open my code and run it, and the program fully works and runs with the database fully integrated._